# Automatically bring up socketcan network interfaces on boot (can0, ...)

Tags: boot, networking

I have a couple of machines that use socketcan for CAN interfaces.

The hardware driver is loaded by `modprobe pcan`, and that module is currently magically configured to start itself on boot, which is working fine.

But every time I reboot, I have to bring up the network interfaces manually, e.g.:

```
sudo ip link set can0 up
sudo ip link set can1 up
sudo ip link set can2 up
sudo ip link set can3 up
```

What is the best way to bring up the `canX` interfaces on boot (and also making sure that they don't come up until the `pcan` module is loaded)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just throw them into your rc.local file

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

```
#!/bin/sh -e

sudo ip link set can0 up
sudo ip link set can1 up
sudo ip link set can2 up
sudo ip link set can3 up

exit 0
```

Comment: I ended up doing this with the addition of a few commands to load and initialize the module first. Maybe I should learn how to set up upstart jobs, though, it seems more appropriate (I guess, although this works perfectly fine). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found a nice [solution using *systemd-networkd*](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/issues/68#issuecomment-584505426) which should work for Ubuntu >=19.04:

To automatically enable all can interfaces, create a file `/etc/systemd/network/80-can.network` with the following content:

```
[Match]
Name=can*

[CAN]
BitRate=500K
```

Instead of "can*" you can also specify a specific interface (e.g. "can0"). And of course you may adjust the bit rate to your needs. See `man systemd-network` for all available options in the `[CAN]` section.

Then (re-)start the systemd-networkd service:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

To have it start automatically when booting:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

Comment: Heey, do you think this would work in combination with networkmanager (which manages my other network connections)?

Comment: I'm currently not at a PC with CAN ports, so I cannot verify but AFAIK network-manager is used per default by Ubuntu.  Since I didn't change anything there, I assume it works.  In any case, you can simply give it a try, worst case you can remove the file again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, and it works fine. `networkd` logs about other interfaces, but doesn't seem to touch them